# Android Emulator not working when opening programs in VS

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator

For some reason my Android emulator doesn't seem to want to boot up when I'm opening a program in Visual Studio. I do have Hyper V set up, and when I start it up via the Device Manager it actually works fine.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU8WQ.png)

But when I try to open up a program, for example I'm trying to start this up https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/Accessibility/
It just says "Cold Boot, Host Hypervision has changed" and stays black forever.
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8IRE.png)

How can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

Your VS version probably doesn't support the Hyper-V based Android emulator. Try to update your VS to 15.8 version or higher, because this feature was introduced in 15.8 version. You can check the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#androidemulator)

Comment: I checked which version of VS I have and it actually is version 15.8. I also checked which version of the Android Emulator included with it is and it also seems to be the latest version.